# Android Realm Query Relationship

Tags: android, realm

I have a Realm Object called TodoList which has a property of RealmList like this.

```
   @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String title;    
    private RealmList<Task> tasks;
```

And I here the Task Realm object

```
   @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String title; 
    private boolean completed;
    private TodoList todoList;
```

My question what is the best way to write a Realm query that returns that list of Tasks that belong to a particular TodoList. Here is my approach.

```
public RealmResults<Task> getTodoListTasks(int todoListId) {
        RealmResults<Task> tasks = mRealm.where(Task.class)
                .equalTo("todoList.id", todoListId).findAll();
        return tasks;
}
```

This approach requires that I query the Task table looking for all the TodoList foreign keys that matches a given id. I was hopping for something like this:

```
 public RealmResults<Task> getTodoListTasks2(TodoList list) {
        TodoList todoList =  mRealm.where(TodoList.class).equalTo("id", list.getId()).findFirst();
        RealmResults<Task> tasks = todoList.getTasks();
        return tasks;

    }
```

However this will not build because I cannot cast RealmList to RealmResult.

Comment: The second approach is the way I'd do it - why do you need a `RealmResults`? Why can't you just return the `RealmList`?

Comment: Thanks Adam, I need RealmResults for RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: With backlink this would be much easier, but unfortunately it has been implemented yet, see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607 . The both approaches are fine. you can actually convert a `RealmList` to `RealmResults` by `realmList.where().findAll()` . The other better abstract object will be added recently to support this use case better, see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2345/ .

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update @beeender. If you want to promote your comment to an answer I will be glad to accept it, the RealmList to RealmResult conversion is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With backlink query this would be much easier, but unfortunately it has not been implemented yet (Mar. 18th, 2016), see http://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607 .

The both approaches are fine. you can actually convert a `RealmList` to `RealmResults` by `realmList.where().findAll()` .

The other better abstract object `RealmCollection` will be added recently to support this use case better, see http://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2345 .

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are querying based on `TodoList` when you actually want to query `Task`s.

The simple solution to this problem is to have the id of the parent also within the child.

```
public class Task extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String title; 
    private boolean completed;
    private TodoList todoList;        
    private int todoListId;
    ...
}
```

Then you can do

```
public RealmResults<Task> getTodoListTasks2(TodoList list) {
    return mRealm.where(Task.class).equalTo("todoListId", list.getId()).findAll();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @EpicPandaForce. I did try your approach, how I has wanted the ability to return a count of the Tasks in a TodoList like todoLists.getTasks().size().

Comment: If your task belongs only to one `TodoList`, then `getTodoListTasks2.size()` gives you that in my case.